# How to save style-css values for Later use then Reload those values back

Tags: jquery, css, c#-4.0, webforms, asp.net-4.0

Having a list of all SQL database-tables and their columns-names, each in `List<string>`

Via a dropDown list control I already chose a table and the columns it has,
then after the first stage, where I have chosen the table and it's columns
I am navigating to a page that's has a `Graphical User interface` like in this screenshot:

[image]

It will then as you could see in the picture, render an html table , with chosen columns as the htmlTable headers .

So now when result is displayed in that `aspx` page,

By using Jquery, I have managed to implement a test-tool.

This enables me to apply some style setting via `Graphical User interface` -  on that table, and for now its just *headers fonts-names*  ,  *headers background-color* and the *columns width* :

**headers fonts** .

fonts are being chosen by an `AJAX ToolKit autoComplete Extender` targeting a dedicated  `asp:TextBox`  with fonts names as its `dataSource`

So on `textchange` event - jQuery is binding selected value...accordingly for a preview .

Same for **background**

By using a jQuery color picker, which with it's `event handler` is doing the job of applying the selected color as the `<tr>` bgcolor ...etc '

Now that I have all chosen css values i need to use those for a webSite application

What is the simplest way to achieve this goal ?

I could think of generating it through a `File.WriteAllText` ,

So that way result will be a  new File created  with text generated text is a head section of `.aspx` webform page (auto generated via `String.Format`)

```
string formatedStyleStr = string.Format(" <style Type=\"text/css\"> #{0} { \r\twidth: {1};", ID values of jQuery's job);
```

That's the idea ...

As the new file name will be `default` with an extension `.aspx`...

Then write into it programmatically `formatted string` as you would manually write it

When usually starting a new `empty website application`.

So instead of using  new form , you will **"add an existing item "**...

or other options I could do to achieve this result. i did not  yet  decide how to ...

only  that i need it to hold  these values that was selected ,

so as you will open this file to work on it via visual studio,  you will have a kind of a template to start with (the initial style is created by the UI in the picture)

what approach is the one I should use ?

as i don't have enough experience in that field ....I wanted to ask 
did anyone think of it  already ...and figured  some ways to implement it.

Comment: I'm afraid I dont fully understand what you are asking.  What is the desired result you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

**ASPX**

```html
<style type="text/css" runat="server" id="AutogeneratedStyle"></style>
```

This will create a field - type `HtmlGenericControl` within the current `page`.

**C# Code Behind**

then just assign the literal CSS definition like this:

```
var generatedStyle= string.Format(

                   "-->#idOfElement here<---
                      {
                          background-color:{0};
                      }", someVariables);

AutogeneratedStyle.InnerHtml = generatedStyle;
```

hope it will help you gettng started