# How to put variable inside CSS

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

Here the example code

Asp.net 4.5.1 - aspx page

`srSelectedLang` is a code behind variable

```
 public string srSelectedLang;//defined at code behind cs file of aspx
```

the below code is aspx code

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <style type="text/css">

        .setPokemonTeamCSS {
            width: 333px;
            height: 38px;
            display: block;
            background: url(//static.monstermmorpg.com/images/pokemoncenter/set_pokemon_team_<%=srSelectedLang%>.png?3) no-repeat top left;
            border-style: none;
            border-width: 0px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
          </style>      
</asp:Content>
```

this example is not working `<%=srSelectedLang%>`

Comment: how is it "not working" ? what exactly is happening?

Comment: you can override this class property in other page where you want to pass this url.

Comment: @Andrew it breaks everything and the variable is not parsed

Comment: @Prashant i don't understand what do you mean

Comment: That's because your variable is inside a string that you're not wrapping properly.

Comment: @Plummer so how can i fix?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG this is working for me. Are you sure that `srSelectedLang` has a value?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG I would recommend defining the entire url var outside the styling and then pop it in.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add code behind vars inside a style section...

There are several things you can do:

1. Manipulate it with JS/jQuery:

   var codeBehindUrl = '<%= string.format("whatever{0}.png",srSelectedLang)%>'

   //on the doc ready method:
   $(".setPokemonTeamCSS").css("background",codeBehindUrl);
2. Make a runat=server element and modify CSS from code behind:

   //page:

   < div id="myDiv" runat="server" class="setPokemonTeamCSS">

   //Code begind file:

   myDiv.Style.Add("background",string.format("whatever{0}.png",srSelectedLang) );

Comment: well this sucks. are there any particular reason?

Comment: I guess it is because the way/order aspx is renderd. Prehaps script tag is ignored by server.

Comment: Here are some more things you can do... (you could apply runat="server" to a style tag lol didn't know that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917194/programmatically-apply-style-to-an-asp-net-website